# Adding an RSS feed to a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, blog, rss, feeds

I want to add a client's blog feed to a Facebook page. Is there a way to do that without using a third party app?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own Facebook App that parses RSS feeds. See http://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not want to use a third party app? Otherwise [ifttt.com](https://ifttt.com/) would be useful. In any other case, you will need to set up your own app.